# Detect if user does not follow the correct flow of an app in django

Tags: django

I'm building an app, it has two basic functions:

1)User has to enter a code or a pin to let him to continue. URL: /enter-your-code
2) The view of the activity (anything do this view). URL: /anything

Thing is, the user always has to enter the code, but what if the user goes directly to the second url without pass to the view of the code? How can I detect if the user does not entered the PIN?

Answer (score 2):

Every view's `request` object has a `session` property where you can store state.

```
def myview(request):
    if request.session['has_pin']:
        # show your "/anything" content
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/enter-your-code')


def my_enter_code(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if check_pin(request.POST.get('pin', None)
            request.session['has_pin'] = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/anything')

     return render('input-pin-form.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this code stay persistent for the user session?

You could always make a model for example:

```
class Code(model.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    session = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()

#####
Views
#####

def enter_code(request):
    # some_code to handle the code entered by the user
    code = Code.objects.create(user=request.user, session=request.session.session_key, code=some_code)


def anything_url(request):
    session = request.session.session_key
    try:
        c = Code.objects.get(session=session)
        # Let user stay on this page
    except Code.DoesNotExist:
        # Here return user to first view
```